# Show simultaneous equations can be expressed in the form Ax = c.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that any system of simultaneous equations as below can be expressed

a<sub>11</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>12</sub>x<sub>2</sub> +...+ a<sub>1k</sub>x<sub>k</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>

a<sub>21</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>22</sub>x<sub>2</sub> +...+ a<sub>2k</sub>x<sub>k</sub> = c<sub>2</sub>

a<sub>k1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>k2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> +...+ a<sub>kk</sub>x<sub>k</sub> = c<sub>k</sub>

in the form Ax = c for A, a k × k matrix and x, c column vectors.

Suppose that A is invertible. Show that Ax = c has a unique solution.

Suppose that A and B are invertible k × k matrices. Are the matrices AB
and BA invertible? If yes, what are their inverses?

I know that these concepts are true (except the last one I'm not sure about), but how would I show them?

Comment: What is this first part more than the definition of a matrix and multiplication with a vector?

Answer (score 0):

For the first, if $A$ is invertible and $Ax_1 = Ax_2 = c$, then $A^{-1}Ax_1 = A^{-1}Ax_2$ so $x_1 = x_2$ which shows uniqueness. (Existence is given by $x_1 = A^{-1}c$.) An equivalent way of seeing this is if you regard $A$ as a linear operator (on a finite dimensional vector space, in this case $\mathbb{R}^k$), then being invertible is equivalent to being injective and surjective. Surjectivity then implies the existence of a solution, and injectivity implies its uniqueness.

For the second, the answer is yes, and there are multiple ways to see this. One way is to use the equivalence of invertibility and a nonzero determinant together with the determinant of the product of two matrices, and another way is to explicitly declare $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and show that this is indeed inverse to $AB$.